# Merge two txt files into one using AWK and add missing items

Tags: text-processing, awk, merge

my goal is merge this two files into one, read first if first item is present in second file update it, if not just copy

- first file `a.txt`

  ```
  AAA;2020-09-01;Y
  BBB;2020-09-01;Y
  CCC;2020-09-01;Y
  ```
- second file `b.txt`

  ```
  AAA;2020-09-01;Y;21/08/2020
  BBB;2020-09-01;Y
  ```
- desired result `c.txt`

  ```
  AAA;2020-09-01;Y;21/08/2020
  BBB;2020-09-01;Y
  CCC;2020-09-01;Y
  ```

I try this code but result missing `CCC` raw, how can I solve this isse?

```
gawk -F, "FNR==NR{a[$1]=$1;next} $1 in a{$1=a[$1]} 1" OFS=, a.txt b.txt > c.txt
```

Comment: Are the first 3 fields always the same in both files, or could `b.txt` have different entries there. If so, what to do? From your example it would seem that you want to replace the entire line of `a.txt` with that of `b.txt` if a matching first field was found.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem with your approach is:

- You are specifying a `,` as field separator, although your files are `;`-separated
- You have enclosed the program in `"` which leads to the shell interpreting `$1` as positional parameters, rather than `awk` interpreting it as fields; you should always enclose `awk` programs in single quotes `'`.
- You are building the "list of replacement values" (stored in the array `a`) from `a.txt`, although you stated it should be based on `b.txt`.
- You are storing only the first field in this list (`a[$1]=$1`) whereas you should store the entire line for a copy from `b.txt` to `a.txt` (i.e. `a[$1]=$0`).
- When the "key" (the first item) was present in `b.txt`, you replace only the first field of `a.txt` with the respective line from `b.txt`, although you should replace the entire line (i.e. `$0=a[$1]` instead of `$1=a[$1]`).

So it would seem that you are looking for something like this:

```
gawk -F';' 'FNR==NR{a[$1]=$0; next} ($1 in a) {$0=a[$1]} 1' b.txt a.txt > c.txt
```

Comment: Good now it's better, I'm in a windows so I replace quote with double, now I try with a real data, many thanks

Comment: works very fine and faster with a many many row, many thanks